# take input until the condition is completed in python

Tags: python-3.x, input, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want to take two input. The program must accept only valid scores (a score must fit in the range [0 to 10]). Each score must be validated separately. If the input is not valid, I want to print "Wrong input".
After taking two valid input, I want to print sum of the values.

```
count = 0
count2 = 0
while True:
    a = float(input())
    if 0 <= a <= 10:
        count2 += a
        count2 += 1
    b = float(input())
    if 0 <= b <= 10:
        count2 += b
        count += 1
    else:
        print('Wrong input')
    if count == 2:
        break

print('Sum = {}'.format(count2))
```

**Sample input:**

-3.5

3.5

11.0

10.0

**Output:**

Wrong input

Wrong input

sum = 13.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking two while loops you can easily verify each input individually till you get the expected value.

```
while True:
    a = float(input())
    if 0<=a<=10:
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong Input')

while True:
    b = float(input())
    if 0<=b<=10:
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong Input')
print("sum =", a+b)
```